# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha \exp(-cn^\beta)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

Let $\alpha,\beta,c>0$. Then I have the strong assumption that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha \exp(-cn^\beta)$$
converges. How would you show that? Using the root test you get only convergence for $\beta>1$ (otherwise the limit is $1$) if I'm not mistaken.

Using the ratio test it might work. For that you would have to show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^\alpha}{n^\alpha} = 1
$$
and
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} (n+1)^\beta-n^\beta>0.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all integers $k \ge 0$ and real numbers $x \ge 0$ is
$$
 e^x \ge \frac{x^k}{k!} \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 n^\alpha \exp(-cn^\beta) = \frac{n^\alpha}{\exp(cn^\beta)}
\le \frac{k! }{c^k } n^{\alpha-k\beta} \, .
$$
Since $\beta$ is positive we can choose $k$ so large that $\alpha-k\beta < -1$, this shows that the series is convergent.

Comment: Great and easy answer, thanks a lot! My approach would work as well, right? But your answer is much better!

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: Yes, the ratio test works as well.

Comment: So your great argument gives us even an upper bound of the series. Namely $$\frac{k!}{c^k}\zeta(k\beta-\alpha)$$ for all $k>(\alpha+1)/\beta$.